# Delphi object to json string how to ignore empty and null fields

Tags: json, rest, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have a class for rest request as follows

```
TRedeemItemsClass = class
private
  [JSONName('RedeemCode')]
  FRedeemCode: String;
  [JSONName('AssetKey')]
  FAssetKey:String;
public
  property RedeemCode: String read FRedeemCode write FRedeemCode;
  property AssetKey:String read FAssetKey write FAssetKey;
  function ToJsonString: string;
  class function FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TRedeemItemsClass;
end;

implementation

function TRedeemItemsClass.ToJsonString: string;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(self);
end;

class function TRedeemItemsClass.FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TRedeemItemsClass;
begin
  result := TJson.JsonToObject<TRedeemItemsClass>(AJsonString)
end;
```

---

```
jObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reqRedeem.ToJsonString), 0) as TJSONObject;
```

Using this line of code I get my json request string like

> {"RedeemCode":"","AssetKey":"xxxxx"}

as expected.

Redeem request body json string should either one of these (
according to information received from the customer **assetkey** or **redeemcode**)

> {"RedeemItems":[{"AssetKey":"xxxxx"}]}

or

> {"RedeemItems":[{"RedeemCode":"xxxxx"}]}

So in the short term, I want to ignore all fields (including arrays) that is empty or nil.

I'm using Delphi 10 Seattle.

Comment: You have to build the JSON "by hand" or write an interceptor for this

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168982/json-empty-array

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below method:

```
function TRedeemItemsClass.ToJsonString: string;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(self, [TJsonOption.joIgnoreEmptyStrings]);
end;
```

or

```
function TRedeemItemsClass.ToJsonObject: TJSONObject;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonObject(self, [TJsonOption.joIgnoreEmptyStrings]);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check it's `nil` condition:

```
if Assigned(field) then
begin
  // do something
end;
```

**or**

```
if field <> nil then
begin
  // do something
end;
```